# WPF WebBrowser with Bootstrap form

Tags: c#, wpf, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project that involves using a WPF WebBrowser to load a form created using Bootstrap JS framework. However, it appears that parts of the form (specifically drop-down select options buttons) do not function within the WebBrowser, despite working normally in IE11. The form does not retain drop-down selected values (on submit, the default value is recorded) and on change commands (e.g. loading specified data) do not work. I have searched extensively but have not found a solution that works. Drop down menus on non-Bootstrap forms seem to work when loaded, but Bootstrap forms on any site I load in the WebBrowser seem to fail.

Steps I have taken already that have not resolved the issue:

- I have changed the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION registry keys (among other keys suggested online) to change the default IE of the WebBrowser to IE11, and I have tested to make sure this is working, but it does not resolve the issue.
- I have checked drop down boxes on other websites within the WebBrowser, which seem to be working fine.
- I have ensured JavaScript is functional within the WebBrowser interface.
- I have checked that the website works in IE11 outside of the WebBrowser interface.
- I have tried the WebBrowser in both a Window and within a Form

I appreciate any help!

Comment: How did you confirm that the browser was working as IE11?  I've used WPF web browser with a bootstrap page and it worked fine.  One thing I encountered was when I set the registry keys I needed to check if the machine was 64 or 32 bit.  When I set the proper key, it worked no problem.

Comment: I navigated to http://www.whatsmybrowser.org/ and it displayed IE 11 as the current browser. I also have set the registry keys to IE 11 for both 32 and 64 bit, as well as for the current user and local machine.